# Dropdown-menu смещается при уменьшении размера экрана

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть навигационное меню. Есть кнопка User с выпадающим меню [навигационное меню](http://jsfiddle.net/kley/z8c8nL7r/1/)

```
<ul class="nav navmenu-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown"> 
        <button  id="user_drop" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" > 
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> User  <b class="caret"></b>
         </button> 
         <ul id="user" class="dropdown-menu nav">
             <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Настройки</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
             <li><a href="#" id="logout_1">Выйти</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

при раскрытии окна на весь экран выпадающее меню находится под кнопкой - это правильно, но при уменьшении размера экрана выпадающий список смещается в лево. Это видно в fiddle. пробовала float, position разные варианты, но список не фиксируется справа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте этому меню

```
right:0; left: auto;
```

и уберите у него float. думаю, этого будет достаточно.

Comment: супер. спасибо. css - это еще то удовольствие для меня )))